# Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins getting error

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

i am getting error while using tailwindcss in my react native project please help me how to fix this error.

Getting error in my react native project:
Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins
This error seems to be related to the configuration of PostCSS or the integration of async plugins in my project. I have checked my project's setup and dependencies, but I am still unable to resolve the issue.
My project setup includes React Native with Tailwind CSS for styling. I have a postcss.config.js file and the required dependencies installed. Despite these efforts, I am still facing the "Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins" error.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error. Please let me know if additional information is needed to better understand the issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by changing the version to 3.3.2 and using yarn instead of npm.

Here are the commands I followed:

```
yarn add nativewind
yarn add --dev tailwindcss@3.3.2
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).